# Flagging row that meets two conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

For a given ID, I am trying to identify the latest observation (last wave or highest wave number) that meets a criteria (=1 or =2)

My data:

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3), wave=c(1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3), var=c(NA,1,2, 1,2,NA, 3,1,3))
```

Outcome:

```
outcome <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3), wave=c(1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3), var=c(NA,1,2, 1,2,NA, 3,1,3), flag=c(0,0,1, 0,1,0, 0,1,0))
```

I can't seem to figure out how to specify to only flag the latest/last row for a given id

```
data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(flag=if_else(var %in% c(1,2) & ...,1,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Subset the 'wave', get the `max`, compare (`==`) with the 'wave' column and convert to integer

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(flag = as.integer(wave == max(wave[var %in% 1:2])))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
#     id  wave   var  flag
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1     1     1    NA     0
#2     1     2     1     0
#3     1     3     2     1
#4     2     1     1     0
#5     2     2     2     1
#6     2     3    NA     0
#7     3     1     3     0
#8     3     2     1     1
#9     3     3     3     0
```

Here, we assume that there are unique 'wave' values for each 'id'

Comment: I updated the example data realizing that there are cases where values other than NA are present and have to be "skipped over".

Comment: @EML Can you please check thee updated answer.  I didn't see your comment as the SO was offline for some time